# jQuery wait until no more text changed

Tags: jquery

I try to understated how I can do the next thing

```
$("#id").keyup2sec(...);
```

i have a function that sends Json when there is keyup, the problem is that it to heavy to send 5 Json for text in legnth of 5.
is three a way the function will wait 2~ secs so only when the person finshed typing and 2 sec passed it will be send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a timeout that is cleared everytime the user hits a key within the given time frame, usually called throttling the event.

Generally 2 seconds is more than normal, but if that's what you want.

```
$("#id").on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout( $(this).data('keytimer') );

    $(this).data('keytimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax(...);
    },2000));
});
```

When the user hits a key, the previous timeout is cleared, so that ajax call never happens, instead it queues a new ajax call that will happen in two seconds, unless the user once again hits a key etc.

Comment: sir can i ask.. this will always clear the 2 sec timeout every keyup until he stops keyup wait for 2 sec and then run the ajax? am i correct? what does it have to do with the `data()` ?

Comment: The timer has to be stored somewhere to be able to reference it later and clear it, hence the use of `data`

Comment: i see this line `$(this).data('keytimer', setTimeout(function() {` is setting the time for timeout.. this is the first time i saw it being set lit this one. do you set it already before even there is a keyup?

Comment: can you [check  this](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/g2cqceac/) i created simple demo from your answer but it does not change the data in `data-keytimer` is that ok?